# Visual Studio 2019 cannot create Project with .NetFramework

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-framework-version

I have trouble with Visual Studio 2019
In past, I install and work well with Visual Studio 2019 in .netframework
But after i reset win, instead of create project with .netframework, it's create with .netcore. I have to change it manually
Can you show me how to set it to .netframework pernament without change manually each project?

Comment: Exactly what project type did you select? You may need to choose a different one

Comment: Need to change the template.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019

Comment: I create Win Form Application, Console App is the same problem  . @HansKeﬆing

Comment: Do not select the template `Windows Forms App`. Is there a template named `Windows Forms App(.Net Framework)` in your VS?

Comment: Oh, i see. There are two different type of Windows Forms App: .NET and .NET Framework at the bottom, i thought they were near, now i know. Thank for taking time to answer this silly question